# Help with solving a triangle inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

I'm trying to solve the following inequalities using the triangle inequality but I'm not sure on how.

I got the following two inequalities:

1. $xf'(x)-f(x)\le \frac {x^2} 2 
   A$
2. $f'(x)-(xf'(x)-f(x))\le \frac{(1-x)^2} 2 A$

$f$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$. I need to show that $|f'(x)|\le \frac A 2: \forall x\in [0,1]$ .

Can I say that $f'(x) \le  \text{(1) and (2)} $ and from the triangle inequality we have:

$f'(x) \le |(1)+(2)|\le|(1)|+|(2)|\le \frac A 2 \left( x^2+(1-x)^2  \right) $

Comment: what is $A$? can't find a reference in the question :(

Comment: It's some number, @Riccardo it doesn't matter for the triangle inequality.

Comment: 1 and 2 are given so?

Comment: You can say they are given. There's no mistake in them. @Riccardo

Comment: $|f'(x)|\le|f'(x)-(xf'(x)-f(x))|+|xf'(x)-f(x)|\le\frac{A}{2}(x^2+(1-x)^2)$

Comment: @OBDA is that it ? are you sure ?

Comment: $\frac{A}{2}(x^2+(1-x)^2)=\frac{A}{2}(1-2x+2x^2)$ and on $[0,1]$ we have $x^2\le x$ then 

$\frac{A}{2}(1-2x+2x^2)\le\frac{A}{2}$

Comment: @OBDA I got to that but isn't there a need to justify that $|f'(x)|\le ....$ ?

Comment: I mean don't you need to justify this: $|f'(x)|\le|f'(x)-(xf'(x)-f(x))|+|xf'(x)-f(x)|$ ?

Comment: @GinKin, the last line of your post might better start "$|f'(x)|=|(1)+(2)|\le\ldots$," instead of "$f'(x)\le|(1)+(2)|\le\ldots$."

Comment: I think, there's one thing missing: Why is $A$ nonnegative ?

Comment: @BarryCipra I didn't see that, that explains the inequality.

Comment: @GinKin $|a|=|a-b+b|$. if $a-b$ and $b$ have the same sign then $|a|=|a-b+b|=|a-b|+|b|$. if $a-b$ and $b$ have different sign then $|a|=|a-b+b|<|a-b|+|b|$.  This is what meant by OBDA's first comment. Also, as Barry suggested, you better start with your line with "$|f'(x)|=|(1)+(2)|\le\ldots$" instead of "$f'(x)\le |(1)+(2)|\le\ldots$". Otherwise, you also need to prove that "$-f'(x)\ge -|(1)+(2)|\ge\ldots$".  This is because "$|f'(x)|\le A/2$" is your final goal.

Comment: @OBDA I need to show that $|f'(x)|\le \frac A 2: \forall x\in [0,1]$ I don't know anything about $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Adding (1) and (2) we get
$$f'\left( x \right) \le \frac{{{x^2} + {{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^2}}}{2}A \le \frac{A}{2}\mathop {\max }\limits_{x \in \left[ {0,1} \right]} \left\{ {{x^2} + {{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^2}} \right\} \le \frac{A}{2} $$
the other case may be considered in a similar way